# Netlogo: double quotes with word command

Tags: string, escaping, netlogo, double-quotes

this one *should* be simple, but..

i would like to define a string in Netlogo which I can then send to the 'run' command. The string needs to include double quotes.

the code below gives *"visit Paris"*

but I want *"visit "Paris" "*

'''
to setup

clear-all

let str "Paris"

let to-do (word "visit " str)

show to-do

; gives "visit Paris"

end
'''

Netlogo Help claims that I should escape the double quote with a backslash, but this does not seem to work, at least in Netlogo 6.2.

any help? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it works perfectly fine if I use a backslash. The difference here is how Netlogo outputs your result. If you use `show`, it outputs the entire string with quotes around it. In that case the `\` is retained since it signals that the following `"` is part of the string and not the end of the string. If you however use `print`, the result is shown without quotes around it and the `\` is dropped, as it is no longer needed to signal that the following `"` is a part of the output.

```
  let str "\"Paris\""
  
  let to-do (word "visit " str)
  
  show to-do ; observer: "visit \"Paris\""
  print to-do ; visit "Paris"
```

As used with my answer to your previous quesiton, it would give you the following, which works:

```
to go-5
  
  run "change-attribute \"attr3\" patches"
  
end
```

See also the output section in the Netlogo [programming guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#output)